# Error Message appearing when running mvn com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:4.6.1:test .Kindly suggest

Tags: maven, grails, groovy, soapui, maven-plugin

Error Message appearing in the CMD:

[ERROR] Plugin com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:4.6.1 or one of its depe
ndencies could not be resolve

Failure to find com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-mave
n-plugin:jar:4.6.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the loc
al repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of c
entral has elapsed or updates are forced

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error since soapui plugins are not available in the repo https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2. Add the following lines to your pom.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>smartbear-sweden-repository</id>
        <url>http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
        <url>http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```